# installed windows 7, laptops finger mouse is way to senstive

Tags: windows-7, laptop, mouse, touchpad

just installed windows 7 on my dell 1720 laptop.

for some reason the mouse is clicking when I don't expect it to.

for example, if I am looking at windows explorer and moving the mouse around, it selects folders and starts moving the folder to another location without me even clicking (dangerous!)

and it also clicks applications when I only single click on the icon.

I changed the click settings of my mouse to closer to 'fast'.

but not sure if this will effect the laptops finger pad (whatever it is called).

Any ideas?

Comment: I suffer from exactly the same problem! Have HP Compaq 6820s laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably install  the drivers for your Touchpad

http://www.synaptics.com/support/drivers

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood the question. You changed the click settings of my mouse to closer to 'fast'? You probably want it 'slow'.

Otherwise, when you bring up the mouse dialogue, does it offer the following screens? If so, you can adjust touchpad sensitivity, as shown.

[image]

[image]

[image]

If not, install mouse driver from Dell [here](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=WLH&catid=-1&dateid=-1&impid=-1&osl=EN&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=INS_PNT_PM_1720&hidos=BIOSA&hidlang=en&TabIndex=&scanSupported=False&scanConsent=False) under "input devices".

Comment: I have a dell 1720, windows 7, and it says the driver is not compatible.  I really need that 'touch sensitivity' option! :)

Comment: I got the link from Dell drivers, 1720. It's the list of Vista drivers which are compatible with W7, so no reason for it not to work. Where did the error message occur? On installation? Is there a way to force it through? If not, go with the synaptic driver suggested by Michael B.

Comment: after it unzips, it runs and says 'this software is not compatible' press ok to exit.  I am running windows 7 64-bit, maybe that's why.  I downloaded the synaptic and it worked fine, but no touch pad sensitivity setting.

Comment: 64-bit? Ah, that explains it. I don't know the success of using 32-bit drivers in 64-bit settings, but Dell doesn't offer it that I can see. Good luck.